# How to import the latest log4j2 from maven in intellij-idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, log4j2

How can I import the latest log4j2 from maven in intellij-idea?
At the time of writing, it's 2.11.2 and it is not in the list when I search for it.

I've searched for 'org.apache.logging.log4j' and '2.11.2' without the quotes. (and a lot of other searches)
If I use google, I can find it in the maven repostiories:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I want to do it through maven because I need the transitive dependencies.
And I need a recent version because I need the 'Delete' functionality.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.2 (latest available version at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 errors in your dependency:

- artifactId should be `log4j-core` (if you want the entire engine) or just `log4j-api` (if you're writing a library and want just the API)
- type `pom` is probably not what you want. You want `jar` which is the default, so type should be removed.

To avoid more typos, copy paste the dependency from:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2

Comment: Thank you very much! I can find it when searching for log4j-core